# Using CSS and HTML, change text-align if text doens't fit in a line

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items to show on screen. This is an example list with two items I would like to have:

[image]

My HTML is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Site</div>
    <div class="value">12 Oak Street, Vancouver</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Note</div>
    <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
</div>
```

The tricky part which I don't know how to accomplish is aligning text of the `value`s. If `value` can fit in the same row, it should be right-aligned. Otherwise, it should start in the next line and it should be left-aligned (like in the image above).

Can this be done with CSS? If needed, I can change the structure of HTML as well.

Comment: What's the CSS you have so far?

Comment: I don't have any CSS so far. General styling is not important to me, just this text-alignment, which I asked. I was playing just with that but unsuccessfully

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, any results? It is much harder than it looks like, right?

Comment: Yes... it's a total sh*t. Removed my answer with even 4 upvotes... I tried using `flex`, `:after`, `:before`..... and many other tricks, but at the end I'm most than positive that you'll end up using 1: a different HTML 2: or JS to detect when to remove the `float:right;` from he `.value` element.

Comment: I don't like the idea to use JS here. Measuring width of the text, it just seems not so clean solution. Especially when it must work on the fly. If you change width of the browser, some event must be triggered for JS to measure text and do its own changes... Just ugly... Changing HTML is completely fine, but still don't know how...

Comment: I'll try to investigate... seems really a great CSS trick - if someone discovers how to do it.

Comment: is `.row` some dynamic width or fixed?

Comment: `.row` has `100%` width, so it depends on its parent.

Comment: Solution where I duplicate values in the HTML is also OK for me. Either way I am generating this HTML on the fly. For example, I was thinking to put two divs with the same `value` text, and with CSS somehow show one and hide another, or do some crazy trick like that, but nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution that works, but it is somehow ugly because it duplicates the text in HTML. But at least, it doesn't need JavaScript. If someone provided a better solution, I would gladly accept it as the right answer.

```css
html, body{height:100%; margin:0; font:16px/20px sans-serif;}

.row{
  padding: 3px 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 420px;
  position: relative;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.value-right{
  color: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.value-left{
  color: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 16px;  /* the same as padding in .row */
  right: 16px; /* the same as padding in .row */
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="label">Site</div>
<div class="value-right">12 Oak Street, Vancouver</div>
<div class="value-left">12 Oak Street, Vancouver</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="label">Note</div>
<div class="value-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
<div class="value-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="label">Something long enough that</div>
<div class="value-right">almost fits in one row, but it doesn't</div>
<div class="value-left">almost fits in one row, but it doesn't</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm hm... your solution uses some background color to mask the duplicate text. Which makes it not usable for cases where a background color cannot be used.

Comment: Another issue in your example is exactly when using the above in responsive design. once some longer `.label` wraps to two lines it'll overlap with the absolute positioned `.value-left` ... so frankly it's not (aswell) a reliable solution. (Now I'm also concerned about SEO and duplicate content...)

Comment: I just ignored the case when label wraps in two lines - not realistic case in my situation... SEO is also not important for me, this is a web application behind login, data comes from database...

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid it's not doable using CSS only,
With JS and some calculations could help to change an element style when it "overlaps" another element.

The closest using plain CSS is this example which will only work when there's either really a small amount of text in `.value` or a really huge amount of text (that will make the float:right element actually span the full available width). Otherwise you'll rin into this **issue**: http://jsbin.com/vazaka/2/edit?html,css,output

<sub>(Don't use before reading the above)</sub>

```css
html, body{height:100%; margin:0; font:16px/24px sans-serif;}


.row{
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:auto;
}
.row .label{
  float:left;        /* yaba */
  color:#aaa;
}
.row .value{
  float:right;       /* doooo */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="label">Site</div>
  <div class="value">12 Oak Street, Vancouver</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="label">Note</div>
  <div class="value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur beatae magni consequuntur. Nostrum veritatis fugit quas rerum, dicta quod consequuntur, deleniti totam consectetur ex eligendi blanditiis quibusdam voluptatibus culpa et.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you put `width:200px;` in the `.row` then value will not fit in that row, it will go to the next row, but it will not be left-aligned

Comment: unfortunately, that case when issue appears is the most common. most often all can fit in one line. when it doesn't, then usually this is because few pixels is missing, and then that issue appears.

Comment: @Luka I explored probably every possible way in pure CSS. There are two major factors unhandleable by CSS alone. 1. detect when element needs to wrap (caused by available space of 2 elements). 2a. When element wraps make text-align: left; or... 2b. Remove all floats -> And make it work both ways (shrink - stretch)

Comment: @Luka A robust and fast JS that uses some throttle on resize, load, etc could help improve performance and get the job done.

Comment: I found something that works. It is ugly because I put the same text twice in HTML. But at least I don't need JS.